# Write the value of Large RasterLayer object to raster, not ID

Tags: r, geospatial, random-forest, raster

I have a LargeRasterLayer object generated from a RandomForest prediction. And it has both ID (integer from 1 to 55) and Value (integer from 1 to 56). But after I wrote it to a .tif raster, and loaded it to ArcGIS, I found the raster showed IDs (1-55) not Value (1-56).

The object is presented as follow:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 865, 1479, 1279335  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.04166667, 0.04166667  (x, y)
extent     : 73.45, 135.075, 17.51667, 53.55833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 55  (min, max)
attributes :
       ID value
 from:  1     1
  to : 55    56
```

And it is generated by `p <- predict(stack,rf)` , where `stack` is a rasterstack and `rf` is a random forest model.

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(terra)
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
names(logo) <- c("red", "green", "blue")
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)

a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
e <- extract(logo, xy[,2:3])
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], e))
v$pa <- as.factor(v$pa)
```

RF model prediction for a categorical variable

```
library(randomForest)
rfm <- randomForest(formula=pa~., data=v)
p <- predict(logo, rfm, filename="test.tif")
p
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
#source      : test.tif 
#categories  : class 
#name        : class 
#min value   :     0 
#max value   :     1
```

You can now load "test.tif" in ArcMap and use the "unique values" display to show the labels (0 and 1 in this case) instead of their integer representation (1 and 2 in this case).